# CakePHP - How to add associated records to a model on save?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.3 and I'm trying to find the correct way to perform associated data saving.
I've setup an image upload form that save picture data but in the mean time I also want to process the saved image such that on save my application should examine the file and extract all the exif data and add that tags as associated models tags.

My relations are

```
Picture hasMany Tags
Tag belongsTo Picture
```

Right now I'm trying to use the Picture beforeSave callback to programmatically add the new records to the data array but it's not working (it's not saving the added data).

**PictureController**

```
$this->Picture->create();           
$this->Picture->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

**Data array after beforeSave**

```
Array
(
    [Picture] => Array
        (
            [field1] => foo
            [field2] => bar
        )

    [Tag] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tag] => example
                    [value] => example
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [tag] => example 2
                    [value] => example 2
                )
         )
)
```

How can I achieve what I want without messing too much with the controller? I would like my business
logic to stay mostly on the model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use deep in order to achieve this. According to the cookbook:

> To save also associated data with $options['deep'] = true (since 2.1)

Examples

```
$Model->saveMany($data, array('deep' => true));
$Model->saveAssociated($data, array('deep' => true));
```

Check the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) for more details

Comment: I've just tried but it's not working. Did you mean in the controller, right? Or I'm supposed to call the save* method in the beforeSave callback?

Comment: yep, you call save method on the controller.. check this examples http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: Even this way the new associated data I "inject" in my beforeSave is not saved.

Comment: wher are you injecting the data? You cannot modify $this->request->data ... you will need to create a copy of that array and then inject

Comment: In beforeSave. In that callback I have access to `$this->data`. I'mg adding the `Tag` key to the array as in my question example code.

Comment: and what's the query that it is being created when you call the controller? does it have the ijected data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36748/discussion-between-pollirrata-and-sangaran)